# dpkg google-chrome corrupt invalid status

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management, google-chrome, dpkg

I can't get this to resolve itself, can I get some help?

```
Setting up google-chrome-stable (34.0.1847.116-1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/google-chrome corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

still getting an error while trying to purge:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  google-chrome-stable*  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 163 MB disk space will be freed.  
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?   
(Reading database ... 505359 files and directories currently installed.)  
Removing google-chrome-stable ...  
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www browser) in auto mode.  
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode.  
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/google-chrome corrupt: invalid status  
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--purge):  
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2  
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode.  
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode.  
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/google-chrome corrupt: invalid status  
dpkg: error while cleaning up:  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 google-chrome-stable  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  
:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for it to succeed in the "purge"

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/google-chrome

I then re-installed from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Comment: after removing the file, does it works perfectly?

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly after removing the file.